# How to get rid of CAPTCHA prompted by Google (while searching)?

Tags: google-search, captcha

I am a programmer and I Google a lot.

**The problem.**

The thing is that it seems that Google finds my search requests fishy (often related to security and compile errors, something casual users won't search for) and asks me to enter CAPTCHAs from time to time.

It all started something about a year ago - I've found myself entering CAPTCHAs a couple of times a week - not really pleasant, but something one can live with. Sometime about half a year ago the situation got worse - Google asked me to enter CAPTCHAs up to five times a day (!), but after some time it eased a bit and lately I've been entering CAPTCHAs about once a week. Last week Google started to ask me double CAPTCHAs (asks one and another immediately. First CAPTCHA was entered 100% correct - I triple checked it).

It is true that I sometimes search really weird stuff but CAPTCHAs keep being asked even for casual queries. Also it happens when I Google on different OSes (Windows/Ubuntu) and in different browsers (Firefox/Chrome), so I suspect that this is something that is relevant to my Google profile.

**What I tried.**

1. Dug through Google account preferences - found nothing useful.
2. Saw some articles and tutorials on the internet ([like this for example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4W7hPXS9_Wo)), but all that I stumbled upon was outdated and didn't help me to solve my problem.

---

So, in the end, what can I do to confirm that I am a human once and for all, or at least reduce amount of CAPTCHAs that I have to enter while googling?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off topic here as per the [FAQ]. Have you considered using another search engine? Preferably one that does not track you like google does? I highly recommend [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/).

Comment: @terdon unfortunately I've found duckduckgo to be slightly less useful when it comes to "hard cases" when I tried it couple of years ago. I'll consider to give it a try now, however, so thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @EugenyLoy - I perform hundreds of Google searches every week.  I do dozens every single day looking for the same material.  I have never been asked to do a captchas there something about your behavior that is causing this check.

Comment: I agree with EugenyLoy. I am also a developer and constantly search for security exceptions etc. Never have I seen a captcha to complete a search in Google. Can you give an example of a search? Are you typing it in Chrome's omnibar or in the search field of a Google web page?

Comment: Check this out. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/hoHVNcuyAEU You might also try a tracert to google.

Comment: @Ramhound and km1 well guys, maybe you are not suspicious enough :) The problem, however exists. I asked some co-workers and I am the only one who seem to have this issue. Our sysadmin affected too actually, but not that hard as me. As for query example - cannot give you something specific, since, how I said it can appear on any search request, even really casual one.

Comment: @km1 Thanks for the link, but it didn't helped me. As for "scan for malware part" - I've scanned my pc with multiple AVs and even used different OSes and physical machines, so this is not a reason of the issue. As for "ask sysadmin to help/contact google" - also tried this some time ago. Google support was vague and generic and didn't responded with anything helpful about this topic.

Comment: I have the same issue. Though not that often. It asks me for a captcha about once a week or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a server on the computer that you are using or have a high amount of traffic going to or from your computer then Google picks up on this and asks you to enter the captcha to check that you are not a computer attempting to Spam or hack WebPages. I run a lot of Internet servers and often use the server computers to access the internet so I come across the captchas a lot. If you do not run a server and don’t know of high amounts of dater then you should check that your computer does not have any malware

Comment: I do not run any public servers on my computer, and it is less likely that there are malware on my pc (checked with couple AVs and also the problem occurs on different PCs and under different OSes).