# Google search thinks I'm a robot

Tags: google-search, recaptcha

**Why does Google think I'm a robot?**

It happens to me pretty much lately.

I haven't changed anything in my searching behavior - I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to go to the search bar and type something I want to search.

[image]

- *I don't remember if it happened to me on the [Google search page](https://www.google.co.il) itself, although I'm barely entering Google search page, so it doesn't mean anything - I'm mostly searching from the address bar.*
- *I have read the about message at the bottom, tried disabling all of my extensions and looked a bit on all of my network activity - but couldn't figure something weird or abnormal.*

Any idea?

---

**EDIT:** Today, also Stack Overflow thought I'm a robot :/

Comment: It could be malware on your network or a dynamic IP address associated with malicious activity that's causing the verification widget to appear.

Comment: Are you having the same problem in multiple browsers? I had a problem with captchas once after changing some privacy settings in Firefox.

Comment: @RobRose I mainly use Chrome, and since it doesn't happen each time I search it's hard to know if it's only Chrome or other browsers as well

Comment: I checked [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45216/) and [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29034/), but there wasn't anything helpful. Besides, its been like 5-6 years since those questions were asked, and a lot could've been changed in that time.

Comment: Maybe I'm a robot 